# how to get the ID of a process executed via setsid

Tags: bash

I'm planning to control some programs (like a media player and a shell) via a webapp,
since the webpage die everytime the user visits it, I decided that the webapp will opens the program with `setsid` and then the webapp will communicate with it through pipes.

Note: I can't use `nohup` becouse something like `nohup bash -i <fifoin >fifoout 2>&1 &` automatically stops.

With `setsid` everything works perfectly, but I cannot kill the process since I don't know the ID of the forked process! ..So, how can I retrive the ID of the  `setsid`ed  process?

I tried something like

```
setsid bash -i <fifoin >fifoout 2>&1
kill $!
kill $$
```

As result, both `kill` don't work, I wont search the ID with `ps -e` becouse I can't kill all the running  `bash -i` shell !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only somewhat intricate methods using `strace` come to my mind.

If you can do without redirecting standard error:

```
read _ _ sid < <(2>&1 strace -esetsid setsid bash -i <fifoin >fifoout)
echo $sid
```

If you need to redirect standard error:

```
strace -o/tmp/filename -esetsid setsid bash -i <fifoin >fifoout 2>&1 &
sleep 1 # Hope 1 s is long enough
read _ _ sid </tmp/filename
echo $sid
```

Comment: I think the use of `strace` is overkill!

Answer (score 0):

You still need to background the process with `&`, otherwise it'll be running in the foreground blocking the following lines from even attempting to execute.

```
setsid bash -i <fifoin >fifoout 2>&1 &
kill $!
```

Comment: Actually, it happens to me that `setsid` does not block the shell. However also using the  `&` does not do the job, infact If i first execute `setsid sleep 50 &`and then `kill $!` returns `bash: kill: (21724) - No such process`

Answer (score 0):

A start point may be:

```
setsid bash -c 'echo $$; sleep 100'
```

It will return the proc id of `sleep`