# How to terminate a Python subprocess started with shell=True if the command being run is setsid

Tags: python, linux, subprocess, kill-process

I'm starting a Python subprocess with this command:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True, start_new_session=True)
```

As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4791612/3483220), `start_new_session=True` (equvalent to `preexec_fn=os.setsid`) allows me to terminate the process with `os.killpg(p.pid, signal.SIGTERM)`.

However, if `command` happens to be something like `setsid sleep 10000`, the process isn't terminated. In Python, how can I terminate subprocesses like these as well?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to get the ID of a process executed via setsid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16299784/how-to-get-the-id-of-a-process-executed-via-setsid)

Comment: Why are you using shell=True?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Because I need to execute shell commands, not just start processes. I don't need to use shell=True specifically, but I need to use something that will allow me to run commands with sh or bash.