# bash setsid nohup ./prog & -- $! not pointed at child process

Tags: linux, bash, shell, setsid

I was trying to get pid of process I ran with `setsid` and which ought to run in background like this:

```
test.sh:

#/bin/bash
setsid nohup ./my_program &
echo $!
```

if I run `./test.sh` it will print a pid of `my_program` process and it's exactly what I need. But if run this commands one by one in my shell like this:

```
$ setsid nohup ./my_program &
$ echo $!
```

It will give me a pid of `setsid` command (or may be something else, but it almost all times gives me pid of `my_program` minus one).

What is happening here? Why results of commands I ran in terminal by myself differs from results of `test.sh` script?

Btw, may be you know some easy way of process which I started with setsid and which I need to run in background?

Comment: Maybe it has to do with setsid's forking behavior? It only forks if it is the process group leader; see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9685973/1735215).

Comment: To get the pid of a process executed via setsid, you may try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19767312/1735215)

Comment: @0range yeah, I think first link is exactly what I needed. Thanks a lot! Could you please write this as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Please try to come up with a title specific enough that folks can know what your question is about (thus, if they're having their own problem with $!, whether answers to your question are also applicable and useful to them) without needing to click through and read it; I've tried to edit it to do that here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Repost of comments above as an answer:

This is because setsid only forks the current process if it is the process group leader. A detailed explanation can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9685973/1735215).

To get the pid of a process executed via setsid, the approaches given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19767312/1735215) may be tried.

Answer (score 1):

setsid will call fork to ensure that it creates a new process group aswell as a new session, hence the resulting pid will not match the pid of setsid. The most clean work-around would be that my_program stores its pid into a file.

When you later want to send kill to my_program, you should check that the pid actually matches a program named my_program via /proc file system or calling the ps command with some magic code around it. (This is a very common method used by many daemons)